# EIP712 - Unable to verify signature return from js

Tags: solidity, contract-development, javascript, keccak, eip712

I am trying to verify a signed message in my smart contract that I generated from javascript. I followed another example but for some reason can't figure out why the verify function keeps returning false.

**Javascript -**

```
    const account = await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
    console.log(account[0])
    const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);

    const domain = [
    { name: "name", type: "string" },
    { name: "version", type: "string" },
    { name: "chainId", type: "uint256" },
    { name: "verifyingContract", type: "address" },
    { name: "salt", type: "bytes32" },
    ];
    
    const identity = [
    { name: "userId", type: "uint256" },
    { name: "wallet", type: "address" },
    ];
    
    const domainData = {
    name: "Test sign",
    version: "1",
    chainId: 5,
    verifyingContract: "....B6621D4", // shortened for the question
    salt: "0xf2d857f4a3edcb9b78b4d503bfe733db1e3f6cdc2b7971ee739626c97e86a558"
    };
    
    var message = {
        userId: 1,
        wallet: account[0]
    };
    
    const data = JSON.stringify({
    types: {
        EIP712Domain: domain,
        Identity: identity,
    },
    domain: domainData,
    primaryType: "Identity",
    message: message
    });
    
    web3.currentProvider.sendAsync({
    method: "eth_signTypedData_v4",
    params: [account[0], data],
    from: account[0]
    },function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }
    const signature = result.result.substring(2);
    const v = parseInt(signature.substring(128, 130), 16);
    const r = "0x" + signature.substring(0, 64);
    const s = "0x" + signature.substring(64, 128);
    
    // The signature is now comprised of r, s, and v.
    console.log("sig "+signature);
        console.log("v "+v);
        console.log("r "+r);
        console.log("s "+s);
        console.log("-----------");
        console.log(message);
        
    }
);
}
```

**The solidity contract -**

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
pragma abicoder v2; // required to accept structs as function parameters

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/draft-EIP712.sol";

contract Test {
    struct EIP712Domain {
        string  name;
        string  version;
        uint chainId;
        address verifyingContract;
    }

struct Identity {
    uint256 userId;
    address wallet;
}

bytes32 private constant IDENTITY_TYPEHASH = keccak256("Identity(uint256 userId,address wallet)");

uint256 constant chainId = 5;
address verifyingContract = address(this);
bytes32 constant salt = 0xf2d857f4a3edcb9b78b4d503bfe733db1e3f6cdc2b7971ee739626c97e86a558;
bytes32 private constant EIP712_DOMAIN_TYPEHASH = keccak256("EIP712Domain(string name,string version,uint256 chainId,address verifyingContract,bytes32 salt)");
bytes32 private DOMAIN_SEPARATOR = keccak256(abi.encode(
    EIP712_DOMAIN_TYPEHASH,
    keccak256(bytes("Test sign")),
    keccak256(bytes("1")),
    chainId,
    verifyingContract,
    salt
));

function hashIdentity(Identity memory identity) private view returns (bytes32) {
    return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
        "\\x19\\x01",
       DOMAIN_SEPARATOR,
       keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
        IDENTITY_TYPEHASH,
        identity.userId,
        identity.wallet
       ))
   ));
}

function verify(address signer, Identity memory identity, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) public view returns(bool) {
    return signer == ecrecover(hashIdentity(identity), v, r, s);
}

}
```

In remix I am passing in the values I get from the javascript to the contract verify function in the following format - `wallet address, [userId,wallet address], v, r, s`

However it keeps returning false. Any ideas?